# Rounding off function provides different value

Tags: java

I am using `math.round()` to round off. this is the code:

```
double value=0.14499999970197677;
double rounded;
rounded=Math.round( value* 1000.0) / 1000.0;
rounded=Math.round( rounded* 100.0) / 100.0;
System.out.println("Final value :" + rounded);
```

My expectation is it should return `0.15` but it is returning `0.14`
Also, if the value is `0.13499999970197677`, then it is returning `0.14`, why not `0.13`
I have already gone through many links related to rounding off. but still not clear.
Please tell me clearly that why this is happening with both the numbers?

Comment: How is this different than your other two questions, both closed?

Answer (score 0):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact.
After the first assignment, `rounded` is 0.145, the multiplication by 100 will be truncated, so it will be something like 14.499999999999 which rounds to 14, divided by 100 you get 0.14 as you have seen.

UPDATE: actually, the division by 1000 will already be truncated, so the result will be more like 0.1449999999.

Comment: Then it should be happening with 0.13499999970197677 also? But I don't see it there.

Comment: OK. Perhaps the results are rounded instead of truncated.